# Surrounded Regions not working for larger input

Tags: c++, image, recursion

I can't make my code work for this problem and am not sure how to find out the reason. It works on small set, but failed at large set.

Given a 2D board containing 'X' and 'O', capture all regions surrounded by 'X'.

A region is captured by flipping all 'O's into 'X's in that surrounded region.

For example,

```
X X X X
X O O X
X X O X
X O X X
```

After running your function, the board should be:

```
X X X X
X X X X
X X X X
X O X X
```

My solution:

```
class Solution {
public:

    void solve(vector<vector<char>> &board) {
        int row = board.size();
        if (row<=1) return;
        int col = board[0].size();
        if (col<=1) return;

        for (int c=0; c<col; c=c+col-1)
        for (int r=0; r<row; r++)
         {
             if (board[r][c]=='O')
                findBdCoords(board,r, c, row, col);
         }

        for (int r=0; r<row; r=r+row-1)
        for (int c=0; c<col; c++)
        {
             if (board[r][c]=='O')
                findBdCoords(board,r, c, row, col);            
        }

        for (int r=0; r<row; r++)
        for (int c=0; c<col; c++)
        {
             if (board[r][c]=='O')
                   board[r][c]='x';
             if (board[r][c]=='B')
                 board[r][c]='O';
        }       
    }

    void findBdCoords(vector<vector<char>> &board, int r, int c, int row, int col)
    {
        if (board[r][c]!='B')
            board[r][c]='B';
              //4 directions neighbor
                        //4 directions neighbor
            if (r + 1 < row && board[r + 1][c]=='O')
                findBdCoords(board, r + 1, c,  row, col);

            if (r - 1 >= 0&& board[r - 1][c]=='O')
                findBdCoords(board, r - 1, c, row, col);

            if (c + 1<col&& board[r][c + 1]=='O')
                findBdCoords(board, r, c + 1,  row, col);

            if (c - 1 >= 0&& board[r][c - 1]=='O')
                findBdCoords(board, r, c - 1,  row, col);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the simplest 9x9, it's clear that an **O is not surrounded if touching a border or connected to an O touching a border.**

If we look at the border as an element that is neither 'O' nor 'X', then we can generalize this rule:
**An 'O' is not surrounded if it is connected to an 'O' that connects with piece that is neither 'X' nor 'O'.**

I'll call this element 'B'.

So you could extend the board with B's ala

```
     BBBBBBBBB
     BXXXOOXXB
     BXOXOOXXB
     BXOOXXXXB
     BXXXXXXXB
     BBBBBBBBB
```

The idea being that even if you throw some B's into the middle, your algorithm should still work.

Then check an O cell for not being surrounded, if connected to a B, good, otherwise check all of its O neighbors using the same function (recursion).

To speed things up you could set a flag for any cell you know is connected.
Here's the psuedocode, I'm sure you could refine it:

```
CheckCell(location)
    if connectedLocations[location] return true
    if checkedLocation[location] return false  // This is critical, it stops the infinite spiderweb of neighbor checking.
    if X return false
    if B() return true // whatever you decide B is.
    checkedLocation[location] = true        
    return connectedLocations[location] = CheckCell(north) || CheckCell(south) || CheckCell(east) || CheckCell(west)
```